# How to replace/connect two values from the same table when they report as null?

Tags: sql

I have a table which has the following format with multiple values;

| s_sym | parent | r_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa.BW | aaa | NULL |
| aaaa | NULL | 12345 |

I have another table which connects to this one through the same r_id.

| r_id | gross | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 12586 | 1/1/01 |

The r_id only has values for the parent column with the s_sym column returning as null when trying to join the columns together. Is there a way to connect the s_sym to the r_id so I can connect the two tables directly together so the results of the query appear something like this;

| r_id | s_sym | parent | gross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | aaaa.BW | aaaa | 12586 |

instead of what currently appears

| r_id | s_sym | parent | gross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | aaaa.BW | aaaa | NULL |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. MySQL `join` is what you need.

Comment: You need to show your current query and clearly explain how you arrive at *aaaa* being the parent value.

Comment: It is what has already been given to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far from clear from your question but presumably you need to join your rows on the first part (ie, before the ".") of the `s_sym` column.

We have no idea of the data types, the rules, or even the database you are using (you should *tag* the database in your question) however, the following produces your desired output, is this what you are after?

```
select t1.r_id, t1s.s_sym, t1.s_sym Parent, t2.gross
from t1 join t2 on t2.r_id=t1.r_id
join t1 t1s on t1s.s_sym like Concat(t1.s_sym,'%')
where t1s.parent is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty simple to me -

```
SELECT TEMP.r_id, TEMP.s_sym, TEMP.parent, T2.gross
  FROM (SELECT T2.s_sym,
               COALESCE(T1.parent, T2.parent) parent,
               COALESCE(T1.r_id, T2.r_id) r_id
          FROM TABLE1 T1
          JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.s_sym = SUBSTR(T1.s_sym, 1, INSTR(T2.s_sym, '.') - 1)) TEMP
  JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON TEMP.r_id = T2.r_id
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6bd59314ae6ee57b0acd7ecd443bb304)

Comment: Thats what I've been doing but because the s.sym does not have a gross amount, the gross returns as NULL. I should probably say that there is another s_sym with the same name as the parent, but it does not have a parent value itself.  I'm looking to connect the s_sym without a parent, but with a gross amount to the s_sym with a parent of the same name, but without a gross amount so they return without NULL values.

Comment: As per your updated sample data, this query would work perfectly. If its not the case plz update your sample data again.

Comment: Edited again, but that query does not work how it is.

Comment: @Liz, s_sym is still not the same for both records. Do you need to match records till first `.` only?

Comment: I need to match the aaaa.BW s_sym to the s_sym with the same name as the parent to be able to first calculate gross and then other things. The two s_sym's are just different types of the same thing.

Comment: @Liz, I have updated my query. Please try now.